# Get item count of a list without getting all properties

Tags: javascript, jsom

I want to get the item count of a list, so my code looks like this:

```
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("tasks");
context.load(list);
```

Doesn't this way retrieve all properties for the list which is unneeded? How can I know the list of properties each object in SharePoint has in order to be able to do something like: `context.load(list,"ItemCount")` for example?

Is there a reference for properties of each object in SharePoint or a way to know these attributes as from what I know using load() doesn't get ALL properties by default

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you only do `context.load(list)` it retrieves a set of properties as you said. And not all. The list of properties that are available for each class can be found in the documentation from Microsoft which is available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193038.aspx

In the case of a list you'll find all the properties that you can retrieve here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj245887.aspx and one of the properties is "itemCount" which can be retrieved by doing `context.load(list, "itemCount")`

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Using **SharePoint Plus:**

```
$SP().list("List Name").get({fields:"ID"}, function(data) {
  alert("Number of items: "+data.length)
})
```

Reference:
http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/

Comment: alternate approach always count +1

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question, these are the properties that are not automatically retrieved through the Client Object Model (if someone can better format this, please do):
: 
  - ContentTypeOrder
  - UniqueContentTypeOrder

- List:

  - BrowserFileHandling
  - DataSource
  - EffectiveBasePermissions
  - HasUniqueRoleAssignments
  - IsSiteAssetsLibrary
  - OnQuickLaunch
  - RoleAssignments
  - SchemaXml
  - ValidationFormula
  - ValidationMessage
- ListItem

  - DisplayName
  - EffectiveBasePermissions
  - HasUniqueRoleAssignments
  - RoleAssignments
- SecurableObject

  - HasUniqueRoleAssignments
  - RoleAssignments
- Site

  - Usage
- Web

  - EffectiveBasePermissions
  - HasUniqueRoleAssignments
  - RoleAssignments

Source: Table 7-1 from [Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Developer Reference](https://books.google.com/books?id=VK5CAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT302&lpg=PT302&dq=2013+Retrieving+a+SharePoint+Client+Object+Does+Not+Retrieve+All+Properties&source=bl&ots=VESQh35uTk&sig=k1_ZjGlNdbbSUMTWLheSvBDYo-E&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiiqOvntdvJAhUGbSYKHbR2BdUQ6AEIRDAF#v=onepage&q=2013%20Retrieving%20a%20SharePoint%20Client%20Object%20Does%20Not%20Retrieve%20All%20Properties&f=false)

Answer (score -1):

Below Call will give you item count of a list.

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('NameOfList')/items", 
   type: "GET", 
   headers: {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"}, 
   success: function (data) { 

         // TODO: handle the data  
       var itemsCount = data.d.results.length;
         alert(itemsCount); 
   }, 
   error: function (xhr) { 
      alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText); 
   } 
});
```

Comment: That does not answer the question, I am using csom not rest, and you didn't answer my other questions..

Comment: lolz...Ok bro :)